# Google Analytics v2 beta 5 for Android causes SIGSEGV

Tags: android, google-analytics, segmentation-fault

I'm having problems with Google Analytics library on 4.x devices.

After calling

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
```

Stacktrace:

```
06-24 10:48:57.865: I/DEBUG(1910): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9300XXEMD2:user/release-keys'
06-24 10:48:57.865: I/DEBUG(1910): pid: 21512, tid: 21547, name: GAThread  >>> pl.otomoto <<<
06-24 10:48:57.865: I/DEBUG(1910): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     r0 5d50cb24  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000008  r3 5fdd7a75
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     r4 5fdd7a75  r5 5fdd7a76  r6 00000000  r7 5fdd7a75
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     r8 00000020  r9 5fdd7a75  sl 00000000  fp 5d50cb24
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     ip 598e3db4  sp 5d50caa0  lr 598cd8cb  pc 40b283e4  cpsr 00000030
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d0  0000000000005000  d1  4059000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d2  0000000100000001  d3  000f4240003d0900
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d4  0000000000000001  d5  000000000000000a
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d6  3ff0000000000000  d7  0000040000000001
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d16 4040000000000000  d17 4040000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d18 0000000000005001  d19 7fffffffffffffff
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fbc71c71c71c71c
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d22 3fcc7288e957b53b  d23 3fd24998d6307188
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d24 3fd99a27ad32ddf5  d25 3fe555b0aaeac752
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d28 0000000000000005  d29 0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-24 10:48:58.160: I/DEBUG(1910):     scr 60000010
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910): backtrace:
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #00  pc 000223e4  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+25)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #01  pc 0001e8c7  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #02  pc 00029013  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+458)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #03  pc 0001590b  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+894)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #04  pc 00018147  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+618)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #05  pc 0002358b  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_connect+18)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #06  pc 0001121f  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl23_connect+1970)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #07  pc 000234c3  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+66)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #08  pc 000209c7  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #09  pc 0001deb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #10  pc 0004d103  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #11  pc 000272e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #12  pc 0002bbe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #13  pc 0005f871  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #14  pc 0005f89b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #15  pc 00054453  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #16  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #17  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910): stack:
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca60  00000008  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca64  40aa2fab  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca68  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca6c  5a727970  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca70  40ad0392  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca74  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca78  c0000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca7c  00000003  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca80  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca84  40b37278  /system/lib/libssl.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca88  5f6296a8  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca8c  4004c4ab  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5326)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca90  5e90e9a8  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca94  40a65a85  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca98  df0027ad  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50ca9c  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #00  5d50caa0  598cdd5d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50caa4  40a6491d  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50caa8  5d50cb23  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50caac  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cab0  0009e7e8  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cab4  5e910238  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cab8  5fdd7a75  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cabc  5d50cb23  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cac0  5d50cb24  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cac4  5fdd7a75  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cac8  00003374  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cacc  5d50cb5c  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cad0  40b37278  /system/lib/libssl.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cad4  598cd8cb  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #01  5d50cad8  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cadc  ffffffff  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cae0  5d50cb23  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cae4  5e910238  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cae8  00000009  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50caec  598cd89b  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50caf0  00000020  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50caf4  40b2f015  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+460)
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):     #02  5d50caf8  00000020  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cafc  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb00  00000075  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb04  00000001  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb08  5fdd7a95  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb0c  40b37278  /system/lib/libssl.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb10  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb14  5fdd7a95  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb18  5d50cb58  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb1c  5fdd7a91  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb20  00001170  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb24  00000100  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb28  40afbe9c  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb2c  5e910238  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb30  00000079  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          5d50cb34  00000000  
06-24 10:48:58.170: I/DEBUG(1910):          ........  ........
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near r0:
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb04 00000001 5fdd7a95 40b37278 00000000  .....z._xr.@....
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb14 5fdd7a95 5d50cb58 5fdd7a91 00001170  .z._X.P].z._p...
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb24 00000100 40afbe9c 5e910238 00000079  .......@8..^y...
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb34 00000000 5fdd7a61 5fdd7a1c 00001170  ....az._.z._p...
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb44 00001173 000011d0 40b1b90f 5d50cb5c  s..........@\.P]
06-24 10:48:58.175: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near r3:
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a54 2e337d88 b0fa4154 c0e3ac9d 31000011  .}3.TA.........1
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a64 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302  .............3t.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a74 70730820 342f7964 73063261 2f796470   .spdy/4a2.spdy/
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a84 70730633 322f7964 74746808 2e312f70  3.spdy/2.http/1.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a94 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000  1...............
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near r4:
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a54 2e337d88 b0fa4154 c0e3ac9d 31000011  .}3.TA.........1
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a64 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302  .............3t.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a74 70730820 342f7964 73063261 2f796470   .spdy/4a2.spdy/
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a84 70730633 322f7964 74746808 2e312f70  3.spdy/2.http/1.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a94 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000  1...............
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near r5:
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a54 2e337d88 b0fa4154 c0e3ac9d 31000011  .}3.TA.........1
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a64 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302  .............3t.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a74 70730820 342f7964 73063261 2f796470   .spdy/4a2.spdy/
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a84 70730633 322f7964 74746808 2e312f70  3.spdy/2.http/1.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a94 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000  1...............
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near r7:
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a54 2e337d88 b0fa4154 c0e3ac9d 31000011  .}3.TA.........1
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a64 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302  .............3t.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a74 70730820 342f7964 73063261 2f796470   .spdy/4a2.spdy/
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a84 70730633 322f7964 74746808 2e312f70  3.spdy/2.http/1.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a94 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000  1...............
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near r9:
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a54 2e337d88 b0fa4154 c0e3ac9d 31000011  .}3.TA.........1
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a64 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302  .............3t.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a74 70730820 342f7964 73063261 2f796470   .spdy/4a2.spdy/
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a84 70730633 322f7964 74746808 2e312f70  3.spdy/2.http/1.
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5fdd7a94 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000  1...............
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near fp:
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb04 00000001 5fdd7a95 40b37278 00000000  .....z._xr.@....
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb14 5fdd7a95 5d50cb58 5fdd7a91 00001170  .z._X.P].z._p...
06-24 10:48:58.180: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb24 00000100 40afbe9c 5e910238 00000079  .......@8..^y...
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb34 00000000 5fdd7a61 5fdd7a1c 00001170  ....az._.z._p...
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cb44 00001173 000011d0 40b1b90f 5d50cb5c  s..........@\.P]
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near ip:
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598e3d94 40059ae1 40059daf 40059d05 40053609  ...@...@...@.6.@
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598e3da4 40b2846f 40b28465 40b2928b 40b27dcb  o..@e..@...@.}.@
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598e3db4 40b283cb 40b2aa45 40b273fd 40b29005  ...@E..@.s.@...@
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598e3dc4 40b2b2b7 40a9aef1 40a9ac3d 40a9ae9d  ...@...@=..@...@
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598e3dd4 40051a1d 40a9aeb1 40a9ab05 40aa1291  ...@...@...@...@
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910): memory near sp:
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50ca80 00000000 40b37278 5f6296a8 4004c4ab  ....xr.@..b_...@
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50ca90 5e90e9a8 40a65a85 df0027ad 00000000  ...^.Z.@.'......
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50caa0 598cdd5d 40a6491d 5d50cb23 00000000  ]..Y.I.@#.P]....
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cab0 0009e7e8 5e910238 5fdd7a75 5d50cb23  ....8..^uz._#.P]
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     5d50cac0 5d50cb24 5fdd7a75 00003374 5d50cb5c  $.P]uz._t3..\.P]
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910): code around pc:
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     40b283c4 20004770 e92d4770 b0854ff0 25004614  pG. pG-..O...F.%
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     40b283d4 46819102 a038f8dd e0264698 46277822  ...F..8..F&."x'F
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     40b283e4 c006f81a d1094562 46281c71 f8cd4451  ....bE..q.(FQD..
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     40b283f4 f7eac004 f8dde952 b1e0c004 0001f10c  ....R...........
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     40b28404 e0091836 0701f105 19e21963 95032600  6.......c....&..
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910): code around lr:
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598cd8a8 f7ed2121 2100ed18 f7ed4620 462aed0e  !!.....! F....*F
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598cd8b8 91006a41 6a834631 93014638 f7ed9b08  Aj..1F.j8F......
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598cd8c8 2000ed10 0000bdfe 4903b91a f00c4479  ... .......IyD..
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598cd8d8 4610b9e1 baf6f00c 00012c9c 4604b538  ...F.....,..8..F
06-24 10:48:58.185: I/DEBUG(1910):     598cd8e8 b92a4615 44794908 eb4cf7ec bd384628  .F*..IyD..L.(F8.
```

Anyone has any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that It relates to one of square libraries that uses OkHttp client.

See: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184

Comment: thx that was the problem and the workaround from the thread fixed the problem. I hope they release the fix soon.

Comment: I don't think that there would be any fix for this. I've heard rumors that OkHttp would be incorporated into next Android release and then it would be automatically 'fixed' :)